# gdal2tiles.py no input file specified, wrong formatting?

Tags: python-2.7, gdal

I'm having trouble running gdal2tiles.py through a command line.  I followed instructions on installing gdal from http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/    I then verified through command prompt that gdal was installed by typing in gdalinfo --version, and the correct version came up which means that my path and variables are set.

So when I try to run this:

```
gdal2tiles.py -p raster -z 0-6 test.jpg abc
```

I keep getting an error that says "error: No input file was specified" and 
"Usage: gdal2tiles.py [options] input_file(s) [output]"

I am able to run other gdal commands and they work just fine. I've also tried to run

```
gdal2tiles.py test.jpg
```

and this gives the same error.

I'm pretty sure I have the right formatting so if anyone has any suggestions or might have a solution to this please let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command prompt just type in:

```
python gdal2tiles.py -p raster -z 0-6 test.jpg abc
```

That corrected the problem for me.